# Android can not get the layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-listview

I am new to Android. when I run my project, I got the following error:

```
Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

it crush on this line:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

**my activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.soft8.sql_test.MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/TheClient"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**and main class:**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private ArrayList results = new ArrayList();
    SQLController   dbcon;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.TheClient);


        dbcon = new SQLController(this);
        dbcon.open();

        dbcon.insertSomeItmes(); 
        results = (ArrayList) dbcon.ReadData();
        lv1.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, results));


        dbcon.close();

    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extend your activity from `ListActivity`, you don't need to define your list again. 
The `ListActivity` automatically looks in the layout set for it for a `ListView` with id "list". If it does not find a `ListView` with id "list" it gives your error.

So change

```
android:id="@+id/TheClient"
```

to

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

and remove definition of your list from activity. (remove findViewById line)

Or just extend normal Activity instead of ListActivity.

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
android:id="@+id/TheClient"
```

to

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

There is no need to `ListView` Cast it because already extends your `Activity` with `ListActivity`

and also remove

```
final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.TheClient);
```

and directly set **adapter** by using

```
setListAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, results));
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential error will come from the fact that you use upper case in your id

```
android:id="@+id/TheClient"
```

try with lower case

```
android:id="@+id/the_client"
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename the id of your ListView

```
 android:id="@+id/TheClient"
```

to

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```

Since you are using `ListActivity` your xml file must specify the keyword android while mentioning to a ID

and remove

```
final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.TheClient);
```

from activity code.

i.e. simply rewrite your code as

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); 



        dbcon = new SQLController(this);
        dbcon.open();

        dbcon.insertSomeItmes(); 
        results = (ArrayList) dbcon.ReadData();
        setAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(this, results));


        dbcon.close();

    }
```